# Run a Fortran executable with an input file with changing variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, fortran

I have a Fortran code that reads an input file using the "namelist" feature. Now, it happens that two for the variables in namelist say `x` and `y`, are to be varied. So ultimately what I want is

```
    do x=1,10
       do y = 2,5
        run fortran code with the new x and y.
       end 
     end
```

Now, there are many other variables in my input file which is read by the namelist in Fortran. So, I am looking for some shell script that can vary that specific `x` and `y` in my input file.

My Namelist file "input.inp" is looking something like:

```
    &BASICS
     x = 1
     y = 2
     H0_CONST = .F.
     T0 = 293
     Ma_in = 1.2 
    &END
```

I basically want to run my program go.exe for multiple values of x and y. Those defined in the namelist are just the initial values plus some additional variables defined that should remain constant. 
My Fortran code looks after file "input.inp" and reads the namelist as:

```
    read(2,nml=basics, iostat=io_stat)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a code in fortran multiple times with different input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650571/run-a-code-in-fortran-multiple-times-with-different-input-parameters)

Comment: your question regards modifying a namelist file using a shell script?  Pretty trivial, what have you tried? You might show what the namelist file looks like and what change you want to make.

Comment: I really think you need to show us your namelist, tell us which variables you need to change and tell us what have you tried so far. Even if you have something very incomplete, it will help a lot.

Comment: If you have a better description of how your `namelist` file looks, and how you want to change it, please do not add comments. Instead, click `edit` under your question and make sure it accurately describes the problem - your initial description has already misled 2 of us...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple script that you can run your program with. Save it as `go` and then you can run your program with all the various NAMELIST files just by typing:

```
./go
```

The `bash` code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in {1..10}; do
   for y in {2..5}; do

      # Generate the NAMELIST file
      { echo "&BASICS"
        echo " x=$x"
        echo " y=$y"
        echo " H0_CONST=.F."
        echo " T0=293"
        echo " Ma_in=1.2"
        echo "&END"
      } > input.inp

      # Now run your program
      YourProgram input.inp

   done
done
```

Before you run it the first time, you must just once, make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x go
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to repeatedly substitute values in a configuration file where your program will read the inputs at each run.

you can do this with `sed` in place replacement in a nested for loop.

for example, for the given file

```
$ cat file
&basics x=1 y=1 &end
```

staying consistent with `bash` conventions, don't have any white space around the `=` signs.

```
$ for x in {1..4}; do for y in {1..2}; 
  do sed -i -r "s/x=\w+/x=$x/;s/y=\w+/y=$y/" file; 
  cat file;  # <-- here run your program instead
  done; done

&basics x=1 y=1 &end
&basics x=1 y=2 &end
&basics x=2 y=1 &end
&basics x=2 y=2 &end
&basics x=3 y=1 &end
&basics x=3 y=2 &end
&basics x=4 y=1 &end
&basics x=4 y=2 &end
```

instead of printing the file, you can run your program instead.

If your variables are not integers, you need to change `sed` matching from word to non-space.  Also for the loop you have to enumerate values this time.  Look at the updated script below...

```
$ for x in 1.1 2.2; do for y in 1.2 3.2; 
  do sed -i -r "s/x=\S+/x=$x/;s/y=\S+/y=$y/" file; 
  cat file; 
  done; done
```

Comment: Thanks but as Vladimir writes this does not help so much really

Comment: @AliThari the code you posted is not where you needed help.  That's why everybody is confused.  Anyway, I wrote this up before you updated the question but i think it's clear now.

Comment: Well done! Have a vote to make up for any unnecessary negativity!

Comment: Thanks @karakfa. Just one comment this seems to work only for integers. Can you tell me what I need to edit if say I want to replace to 1.2,1.3 etc.

Comment: "seq" command may also be useful to generate a lot of 1.2, 1.3, ... etc (e.g. "for i in $(seq 1.0 0.1 100.0); do sed ...)

Comment: this could be made cleaner (more readable) if you set up your template file with unique strings to be replaced. Then it would be like "s/x_value/$x/"